# Python Pandas: compute mean of one column grouped by two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have the following dataframe:

```
         CustID     Condition      Month        Reading  Consumption
0     108000601         True       June       20110606      28320.0
1     108007000         True       July       20110705      13760.0
2     108007000         True     August       20110804      16240.0
3     108008000         True  September       20110901      12560.0
4     108008000         True    October       20111004      12400.0
5     108000601        False   November       20111101       9440.0
6     108090000        False   December       20111205      12160.0
7     108000601         True    January       20120106      11360.0
8     108000601         True   February       20120206      10480.0
9     108000601         True      March       20120306       9840.0
10    108000601         True      April       20120410      12560.0
11    108000601         True        May       20120507       9120.0
12    108008902         True       June       20120606      11520.0
13    108034877         True       July       20120707      14160.0
14    108000601         True     August       20120804      14000.0
15    108007000         True  September       20120906      14880.0
```

I'm trying to compute the mean Consumption of each Condition per month using this groupby,

`monthStats = dfm.groupby(['Month','Condition']).Consumption.mean()`

but am not getting the correct mean. It appears to only be giving me consumption of one CustID instead of all consumption per month per condition.

The format in which the output provides is exactly what I'm looking for, but the consumption results look incorrect. What am I missing in trying to compute mean consumption?

Here is the format the current groubpy outputs.

```
Month  Condition   Consumption
April  True        13795.511299
       False       160.811111
August True        11873.566197
       False       30.593478
```

Comment: It looks good to me. The output you posted is from the whole dataset, right? There is no `April & False` row in the dataset you posted, but the output shows them. When I ran the code it produced correct results. Try to run `import numpy as np` and  `dfm.groupby(['Month','Condition']).Consumption.agg(np.mean)` if that makes difference.

Comment: The above is just a sample of the dataset. The actual dataset contains 5000+ samples.

Comment: OK, see my edited comment above (try using `agg(np.mean)`. Also there is a typo in column name (condtion -> condition) i am not able to edit since it is just 1 character.

Comment: hmm. same result. maybe the way i was verifying it (in excel) was incorrect. dunno. but thanks for the second pair of eyes.

Comment: Strange. If you run the code against the sample you provided it is correct and in theory the code should do exactly what you want. GL :)

Comment: A thing just came to my mind how to verify results. Try:  
`dfm[(dfm.Month == 'April') & (dfm.Condition == True)].mean() #or dfm.Condtion == 'True' if condition is string called "True" and not boolean value`. This should give you the number you are looking for aswell, so you can compare the results with the groupby method :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I get home. I forgot to  push my code last night. Maybe I should change the question to "how to verify mean() results".